# Determine the formula for number of permutations problem

Tags: combinatorics

The task is to find the number of pairs $(a, b)$ of integer arrays of length $n$, where the following conditions are met:

All elements of $a$ and $b$ are integers from $1$ to $m$.
For any $1\le i\le j\le n$, $\min(a_i, b_j) = \min(a_j, b_i)$.
Here's the general formula to calculate the number of such pairs:

Number of pairs $(a, b) = m^{n-1}$

Where:

$n$ - the length of the arrays.
$m$ - the maximum value for the elements in the arrays (from $1$ to $m$).

This formula is based on the observation that for each element $a$ and $b$ in the arrays, you can choose any value from $1$ to $m$, and this operation does not violate the condition that $\min(a_i, b_j) = \min(a_j, b_i)$ for all $i$ and $j$ from $1$ to $n$.

Therefore, the total number of possible pairs $(a, b)$ is $m^{n-1}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Perhaps there is a language issue here...what is an "entire array"?  What does "for which the next step of the mind is determined" mean?  What is the source of this problem?  Can you link to the original text?

Comment: What is your question?